# postgres - two roles working on the same objects

Tags: postgresql

I have a DB with many objects. All are owned by a role called `app`. This role is currently used by everyone and everything (manual users, rollout scripts, app itself ...).

The goal now is to have a shorter `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` for manual users than for the rollout scripts.

I was told that creating a new role for manual users is the way to go. For simplicity, let's say there is only one manual user `frank`.

The goal would be that `frank` can `create/alter/drop` every object he or `app` `created/owns` and that `app` can `create/alter/drop` every object he or `frank` `created/owns`.

This seems difficult in postgres due to the way it works (creator = owner, only owner can alter/drop etc...).

Searching the internet for a solution only brings partial and quite complicated solutions such as [event trigger on create table](https://blog.hagander.net/setting-owner-at-create-table-237/) or not forgetting to issue `set role` always.

What is the best practice here?

*** Update: one suggestion below is to grant app to frank, but that does not do the trick. It causes the scenario that app can not modify objects created by frank:

```
CREATE ROLE "app" LOGIN;

CREATE ROLE "frank" LOGIN;

GRANT "app" TO "frank";

set role app;

create table created_by_app (id int);

set role frank;

create table created_by_frank (id int);

drop table created_by_app; -- works

set role app;

drop table created_by_frank; -- does not work

-- SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: must be owner of table created_by_frank
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single owner, like the "app" role, and let other inherit this role. Something like this:

```
CREATE ROLE "app" LOGIN;

CREATE ROLE "frank" LOGIN;

GRANT "app" TO "frank";
```

When "app" is the owner of a table, "frank" can still make changes to this table or even drop this table.

---

An [event trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-event-triggers.html) could solve the issue that user might forget to set the ownership of a table. The function and the trigger could be something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tr_set_table_owner()
RETURNS event_trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    _table_name     TEXT;
    _schema_name    TEXT;
    _ddl_owner      TEXT;
BEGIN
        SELECT 
              objid::regclass
            ,   schema_name
        FROM    pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
        WHERE   object_type = 'table'
        AND     command_tag = 'CREATE TABLE'
        INTO _table_name, _schema_name;
        
        IF FOUND THEN
            _ddl_owner := format('ALTER TABLE %I.%I OWNER TO app;', _schema_name, _table_name);
            
            RAISE NOTICE 'DDL: %', _ddl_owner;
            
            EXECUTE  _ddl_owner;
        END IF;
END;
$$;


CREATE EVENT TRIGGER name
    ON ddl_command_end
    EXECUTE FUNCTION tr_set_table_owner();
```

Any new table created in your database, should now be assigned to the role "app". If you want this for other objects as well, just change the code in the trigger function.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work, see my update above.

Comment: Role "frank" created a table, but didn't set the ownership at all, just used the defaults. An owner can assign an object to a different owner.

Comment: ty. but that would mean that my users like "frank" must never forget to assign ownership to app of everything they create. so this is asking for trouble ^^

Comment: The entire set up is imho asking for trouble, I would never ever have a bunch of users randomly create, alter or drop tables and other objects. You could create a trigger that sets the ownership, but that would solve just a small part of your problem.

Comment: @Peter: See the event trigger, this avoids the issue that a user might forget the ownership of a table.